# How to create multiple paragraphs with Javascript with shorter code?

Tags: javascript

I want to create multiple paragraphs with each two inputfield with Javascript.
I wanted to know, if there is a way to have a shorter code but the same result?

It should have the same result like this but with a shorter code:

```js
var para1 = document.createElement("p");
    var i1 = document.createElement("input");
    var i2 = document.createElement("input");
    para1.appendChild(i1);
    para1.appendChild(i2);
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para1);

    var para2 = document.createElement("p");
    var i3 = document.createElement("input");
    var i4 = document.createElement("input");
    para2.appendChild(i3);
    para2.appendChild(i4);
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para2);

    var para3 = document.createElement("p");
    //etc.
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Have you encountered loops yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not think of any other solution than using a for loop 
This definitely reduces the code by half length though.

```js
numberOfParagraphs = 3
for(let i = 0; i< numberOfParagraphs;i++){
    var para= document.createElement("p");
    var i1 = document.createElement("input");
    var i2 = document.createElement("input");
    para.appendChild(i1);
    para.appendChild(i2);
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code into a function

```
function createPara() {
  var para1 = document.createElement("p");
  var i1 = document.createElement("input");
  var i2 = document.createElement("input");
  para1.appendChild(i1);
  para1.appendChild(i2);
  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para1);
}
```

Call the function n times

```
createPara()
createPara()
```

Additionally you can pass params such as class, id etc.

Answer (score 0):

well the way you have it written, you are executing the exact same code multiple times. why not put it in a function?

```
createPara();
createPara();
createPara();
//etc.

function createPara() { 
  var para2 = document.createElement("p");
  var i3 = document.createElement("input");
  var i4 = document.createElement("input");
  para2.appendChild(i3);
  para2.appendChild(i4);
  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para2);
}
```

Comment: Why not make a document fragment. It will save multiple re-rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Create a document fragment and append it to DIV instead of creating individual elements.

In the current setup, HTML elements will reflow each time you append any element.

With DocumentFragment you can save multiple reflows as it reflows only once when attached.

Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment for information.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code into a function and give it number of para :

```
    function createPara(n) {
      let parentDiv = document.getElementById("div1")

          for(let i =0; i<n; i++){

             let para = document.createElement("p");
             let i1 = document.createElement("input");
             let i2 = document.createElement("input");
             para1.appendChild(i1);
             para1.appendChild(i2);
             parentDiv.appendChild(para);
         }
      }
   }
```

Call the function and give it the number u want to repeat for exemple 5 time :

```
createPara(5)
```

you can also give it the number of inputs

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would do something for a more general case, but might have gotten a bit carried away; anyway:

```js
const new_children = [
  { tag: 'p', children: [
    { tag: 'input' },
    { tag: 'input' },
  ] },
];

const element_for_def = (def) => {
  const element = document.createElement(def.tag);
  
  if(def.children && def.children.length > 0)
    append_children_to_ele(element, def.children);
  
  return element;
};

const append_to_element = (parent) => (child) => parent.appendChild(child);

const append_children_to_ele = (parent, children) =>
  children
    .map(element_for_def)
    .forEach(append_to_element(parent));

const three_new_children = [1,2,3].reduce(acc => acc.concat(new_children), []);

append_children_to_ele(document.getElementById("div1"), three_new_children);
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ma** is a reference to an **element object** which you want to create multiple paragraphs.
I use **10** for multiple paragraphs line. You can use your required number.

```
let ma = document.getElementById("multiple-para").innerHTML;

for(var i =0; i<10; i++){
document.write(ma + "<br>");
}
```